# How to target Elements specifically in DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

```
<html>
</head>
<body>
<div class="class1">
<p>text to change1</p>
<p>text to change2</p>
<p> </p>
</div>

<div class="class2">
<p>text to change1</p>
<p>text to change2</p>
<p> </p>
</div>

<button onclick="obj1.changehtml()">changehtml</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
var change= function()
{
}
change.prototype.changehtml=function()
{
// targeting specific elements positions
var paragraph=document.getElementsByClassName("class1");
paragraph[0].innerHTML="hello";
paragraph[1].innerHTML="hell1";
var addthem = paragraph[2].innerHTML = second;

}

var obj1= new change;

</script>

</body>
```

In the above program I am facing an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined
```

when trying to change the second paragraph[1].innerHTML element in first class(Class1) using property. 
How do I proceed here?

Comment: `var paragraph=document.getElementsByClassName("class1");` will get the `div with class="class1"` and not the `<p>` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code you were missing `[0].children` after getting the `.class1' elements. Also you should note this returns a NodeList of matched elements not individial elements.

If you have used jQuery before this can make you feel that this would be the native javascript functionality allowing you to chain dom methods to the NodeList but unfortunately it is not.

```js
var change = function(){}

change.prototype.changehtml = function(){
  // targeting specific elements positions

  // okay selector 
  // var paragraphs = document.getElementsByClassName("class1")[0].children;
  // okayer selector
  // var paragraphs = document.getElementsByClassName('class1')[0].getElementsByTagName('p')

  // better more explicit selector  
  var paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll('.class1 > p');
  console.log( paragraphs )
  
  paragraphs[0].innerHTML="hello";
  paragraphs[1].innerHTML="hello1";
  
  // second is not defined
  var addthem = (paragraphs[2].innerHTML = second);

}

var obj1= new change;
```

```html
<script src="http://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/WrQapG.js"></script>
<div class="class1">
<p>text to change1</p>
<p>text to change2</p>
<p> </p>
</div>

<div class="class2">
<p>text to change1</p>
<p>text to change2</p>
<p> </p>
</div>

<button onclick="obj1.changehtml()">changehtml</button>
```